# Get word under cursor(caret) in Eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, content-assist

I'm adding content assist to my custom editor (`IEditorPart`) and I need to get the word that is being written so I can use that word (or part of the word) as a prefix to calculate the competition proposals. The code to retrieve the proposals is working fine but currently I'm hardcoding a prefix just for testing purposes, but now I only need to get the word under the caret and use it instead of the hardcoded string, I tried many possible solutions but nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you using for proposals? `IContentAssistProcessor`, for example, already gives you the text viewer and offset.

Comment: I'm ussing `ICompletionProposalComputer`, but I'm going to explore `IContentAssistProcessor`.